# regdeletekey returning file not found

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I've been playing with this and I can't understand why the RegDeleteKey function is resulting to a file not found error..

I created this test key and it **exists**. HKLM\Software\test
I am also the administrator of this computer. OS is Vista 32 bit.

```
int main()
{
    HKEY hReg;
    LONG oresult;
    LONG dresult;

    oresult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\test", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hReg);

    if(oresult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
            cout << "Key opened successfully." << endl;
    }


    dresult = RegDeleteKey(hReg, L"SOFTWARE\\test");
    if(dresult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "Key deleted succssfully." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if(dresult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            cout << "Delete failed. Key not found." << endl;
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    RegCloseKey(hReg);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

key opened successfully
delete failed. key not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724845(VS.85).aspx) page, the second parameter is a subkey of the key in hKey:

> The name of the key to be deleted. It
>   must be a subkey of the key that hKey
>   identifies, but it cannot have
>   subkeys. This parameter cannot be
>   NULL.

That means your code actually tries to delete HLKM\SOFTWARE\test\SOFTWARE\test.

You probably want to try something like:

```
RegDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\test");
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724235(VS.85).aspx) may come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to check for error 2 / "file not found":

- Make sure it's not a "value" within a key instead of an actual key.

If you create a folder like HKCU > Software > CompanyName and then store a value like option = "foo" with RegSetValueEx, then you need to delete this with RegDeleteValue or RegDeleteValueEx.

- If it's a 64-bit OS, there are separate registry views for 32-bit vs. 64-bit.  By default a 32-bit app will use the 32-bit view for everything but if you created the entry using KEY_WOW64_64KEY for some reason then you need to use that when deleting.